# Converting Dict Into a List

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary like this:
`{5:1, 2:5, 1:3, 7:-1, 3:7}`

How can I convert it to this?
`[2, 5, 1, 3, 7]`

The code that should be written is the second item's key should be the first item's value.

Comment: Is this a school assignment of sorts? And exactly what is the logic behind the outcome/result? I mean, the sorting is all weird.

Comment: What do you mean by "second item's key should be the first item's value"? Your list is just all the keys of the dictionary, but in a different order.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure what you mean by your question, because the keys and values share the same numbers, so it's unclear as to what your test case is showing. Could you please give an updated test case with unique property and value numbers? E.g., what should the output be if the input is `{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7:8, 9:10}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like a homework problem and doesn't include the OP's efforts to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the value of a dictionary entry defines the next key. So we have to find the start key first and add that to our result list. Then we use a loop to get the next dictionary entry and add the key to the result until the value is less than 0.

To find the first element of the sequence we look for a key that doesn't exist as a value.

```
k, v = [(k, v) for (k, v) in d.items() if k not in d.values()][0]
result = [k]
while v > 0:
    result.append(v)
    v = d[v]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to start your code:

```
d = {5:1, 2:5, 1:3, 7:-1, 3:7}
l = []
def dictToList(dict):
    for i in d.keys():

        l.append(i)
    print(l)
dictToList(d)
```

Comment: Why not just, `l = list(d.keys())`?

Comment: It returns the same result. So, it is possible too.

Comment: I think there's a requirement for a specific order, but I don't really understand it.

Comment: As far as I can see the value is the key of the next element.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution:

```
d = {5:1, 2:5, 1:3, 7:-1, 3:7}

l = list(d.keys())
```